# Can I const_cast c_str() if the string is const?

Tags: c++

I have found a lot of examples from stack overflow, but those examples are based on non-const std::string. What if the string is const(top level and non top level)?

```
std::string encrypt(std::string const &input)
{
  //do something, ArrayGuard is a smart pointer to guard the raw char* delete by free
  ArrayGuard<char> guard(encrypt_str(const_cast<char*>(input.c_str())));

  return std::string(guard.get(), std::strlen(guard.get()));    
}
```

case 1(non top level?) :

```
std::string input = "abcde";
std::string encrypt_password = encrypt(input);
```

case 2(top level?) :

```
std::string const input = "abcde";
std::string encrypt_password = encrypt(input);
```

I am **sure** that the encrypt_str **would not** alter the char* I pass into it(if it is possible, I would like to ask them to fix this non const correction api).

ps : I am not sure that I am fully understanding what is top level const/&/&&/volatile, that is why I put "?" behind the case

Comment: If this is C++11, use `&str[0]` **carefully** (like not letting it touch the null character). If not, use a vector or something. There's always the off chance it changes to modify something later without changing the interface.

Comment: Any good reason not to correct the signature of `encrypt_str`?

Comment: @ David Rodríguez - dribeas it takes time, and I don't think they consider const correctness is important by now.

Comment: @ghostofstandardspast we are not using c++11(although I like it).I would change it back to the c++98 style to avoid misunderstanding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule you have to watch out for regarding `const_cast` is that if you use it to modify an object that was originally declared as `const`, then you get undefined behaviour.

As long as you're sure this doesn't happen, you're good.

The constness of the `std::string` doesn't make any difference. Even if the `std::string` is not `const`, the `c_str` function still returns a `const char*`. Nothing changes when you make the `std::string` `const`.

Comment: Agree on the first count, not so much in the second. Whether the original object is const or not matters for the case where you want to attempt a modification. The `c_str()` return a `const char*`, but that  does not mean that it points to a `const char` (it can point to a non-const char).

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Yes, I agree. The last paragraph is written with the assumption that the `encrypt_str` function really does not modify the string.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas You are not allowed to try to modify the character pointed-to by `c_str()`. Even if it happens physically to point to a non-const char, you must treat it as a const char. For example, two strings might share storage, so modifying the character corrupts an unrelated string.

Comment: @raymond: aren't COW strings forbidden in c++11? [you are right that without context I should not assume that, specially since a common implementation still does COW --gcc]

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas There's no point discussing what an implementation might do. Writing to the pointer returned by `c_str()` invokes UB. (Theoretically, an implementation could copy the string to a new block of memory, write-protect that memory, then return that memory from `c_str()`, and if a write protect exception occurs, it reformats your hard drive.)