# Passing a string to a char array, then modify the char array at position x in C

Tags: c++, arrays, string

So I have a string which contains `"RGGB"` and I need it to be in a `char` array to perform some operations. Then I need to replace certain characters for a blank space, for example the first `'G'`, so that my `char` array remains `"R GB"`.

How can I do this? So far I tried this solution:

```
int main()
{
    string problem="RGGB";
    const char *p=problem.c_str();
    p[1]=' ';
    return p;
}
```

I get the error:

> assignment of read only location `*(p + ((sizetype)i))`

Comment: it is very obvious that you can not set something in const var. you may try , char *p = strdup(problem.c_str());

Comment: What operations do you need to do on a `string` that that you need to convert it to a `char*`?  Anything you can do with a `char*` you can do with a `string`

Comment: I believe you can try the following: char* p = &problem[0];

Comment: I tried strdup(problem.c_str()); but I get: 'strdup' was not declared in this scope, should I include something at the beginning of my code to make it work?

Comment: you want #include<string.h>

Comment: `strdup` is non-standard.

Comment: Besides @adem, did anyone note that he is trying to change a const variable with his array call?

Comment: @DavidPulse Er, that's what the question's about.

Answer (score 2):

To access the "interal string" (I mean a `const char*`) of a `std::string`, there are two member functions provided: [`std::string::c_str`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) and [`std::string::data`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/). Until C++11, the difference was that `std::string::data` wasn't bound to return a pointer to a null-terminated `const char*` while `std::string::c_str` was. Now, they are equivalent. And both return a `const char*`, even before C++11.

There are several approaches to your problem:

1. Use `std::strdup` or `std::str(n)cpy` to duplicate the string and write to the duplicate.
2. Use a `const_cast`. Pretty drastic, but, [if it doesn't hurt any rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298212/can-i-const-cast-c-str-if-the-string-is-const) (FYI, it does), works.
3. Don't use `std::string` at all. Do what you want with a `char*` and then optionally convert it to a `std::string` later.
4. Just use the functionality of `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

> p[1]=' ';

is not valid as const char * is read-only pointer.

in other words, it is a const pointer.

remember:

> When const appears to the left of the *, what's pointed to is constant, and if const appears to the right of the *, the pointer itself is constant. If const appears on both sizes, both are constants.

this code might work:

```
char problem[]="RGGB";
char* p = problem;
p[1]=' ';
cout<<problem;
```

Answer (score 0):

string, a C++ class, does not provide directly alterable access to its innerds via a char *. While you could cast away the const, this is dangerous because compilers may use the const as an optimization path.

If you absolutely need to do this just use a char array, not a string or alter the contents of the string using string methods.

Comment: "string […] does not provide directly alterable access to its innerds via a char *", what about `&str.at(0)`?

Comment: str.at(0) provides a const reference as well. If the contents of a string were user alterable it would break compiler optimizations and memory layout sharing. You can always cast away const as C++ allows dangerous things but it makes you do it on purpose. It might work now on some or even all compilers but it could well fail to work on future compilers even from the same vendor.

Comment: Uhm, `at` also has a [non-const overload](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/at). Taking the address from that yields a `char*` that you can use to modify the string _perfectly legally_. (as long as you don't add a `'\0'` in the middle or modify the terminating `'\0'`)

Comment: I stand corrected. I noticed that str[0] also returns a non const ref. in addition to a const ref so it should be usable to directly write to a string element. Always assumed otherwise given that  c_str() doesn't do that. I suppose it's so implementers can peel off a copy and add a null for C library functions without having to store a \0 at the end of each string.

Comment: Don't string objects allow \0s in the middle? I thought the only reason to avoid that was for use with old C functions via c_str()?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in your question:

> I need it to be in a `char` array

Then *put* it in a `char` array:

```
char problem[] = "RGGB";
problem[1] = ' ';
```

Problem solved.

If, on the other hand, you want to solve the problem using *actual* C++:

```
std::string problem = "RGGB";
problem.at(1) = ' ';
```